# コマンドでインストールされているOfficeのbit情報を取得したい

Tags: windows, cmd, ms-office

Windowsのコマンドプロンプトを使用して、インストールされているOfficeが32bit版か64bit版かどうかの情報を取得したいです。

下記のコマンドでインストールされているOfficeソフトの名称・バージョンは取得できるのですが、
何bitなのかはわかりませんでした。

```
wmic product where "Name like '%%Office%%'" get name,version
```

どのようなコマンドを使用すればbit情報を取得できますでしょうか。

環境はWindows 10 Pro です。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: この記事 [Relevance to get MS Office architecture (32 or 64 bit)](https://forum.bigfix.com/t/relevance-to-get-ms-office-architecture-32-or-64-bit/25545) で、`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office`と`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office`のどちらの配下にOfficeのどれかのexeが存在するかで確認しているという発言があります。

Comment: @kunif ご回答ありがとうございます。
提示していただいた内容で無事bit情報を確認することが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

実際には単独のコマンドがあるかもしれないし、もっと短く出来るかもしれませんが、以下の様なバッチを組めば判定できるでしょう。
[Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868)

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem 関連付け判定  Wordなら .docx  Excelなら .xlsx
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('assoc .docx') do @set workrel=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('ftype %workrel%') do @set workpath=%%a

rem インストール判定  Wordなら winword.exe  Excelなら excel.exe
echo %workpath% | find /i "winword.exe" >NUL
if %errorlevel% geq 1 goto notinst

rem OSが32bit版か判定
if "%ProgramW6432%" == "" goto x86

rem OSが64bit版でOfficeが64bit版か判定
echo %workpath% | find /i "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
if %errorlevel% geq 1 goto x64

:x86
echo Officeは32bit版です。
exit /b 1

:x64
echo Officeは64bit版です。
exit /b 2

:notinst
echo Officeはインストールされていません。
exit /b 0
```