# C#、もしくはVBA(API?)で、インストールされているMS Officeのビット数を調べたい

Tags: c#, vba, ms-office

現在でも、Officeが32bitか64bitかが混在しているさなかだと思いますが、それを
C#やVBAのコードでPCにインストールされているOfficeのbit数を取得できる方法を探しています。

手動で確認する方法は解っていますが、それをコードで実現したいのです。

使用する言語は、C#かVBAだけです。もちろんAPI等も触るかと思います。

お分かりの方がいましたら、回答をお願いいたします。

Comment: このあたりの記事が参考になりそうです。[VBA 32Bit版と64Bit版でDeclareステートメントの宣言を分ける方法 - Office 2010,2013](https://www.saka-en.com/office/vba-32bit-64bit-declare-statement-branch/), [Excel VBA インストールされているExcelが64bitか32bitかを返す関数 ExcelIs64bit](https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/c189544333af84e07f65), [条件付きコンパイル（32ビット64ビットの互換性）](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba4/EXCEL269.html), [Office の 32 ビット バージョンと 64 ビット バージョン間の互換性](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office) 2つ目にあるARM版は変わるかもしれませんが。

Comment: 関連質問: [コマンドでインストールされているOfficeのbit情報を取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62831)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#からやるなら、こんなんでどうでしょう。
※エラー処理は適当です。

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleNetApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsWow64Process(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            out bool Wow64Process
        );

        private static bool? IsExcel32Bit()
        {
            bool? result;
            dynamic app = null;
            try
            {
                var excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
                if (excelType == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                app = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
                var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
                if (procs.Length == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                if (!Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                bool bWow64;
                if (!IsWow64Process(procs[0].Handle, out bWow64))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                result = bWow64;
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (app != null)
                {
                    app.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
                    app = null;

                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsExcel32Bit());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

dynamic型がコンパイルエラーになる場合、Microsoft.CSharpを参照に追加してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。素晴らしいです。おかげでやりたかったことがスムーズにできるようになりました!これからも何かありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 32bitOSだと、IsWow64ProcessのbWow64がfalseになるようなので、Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem の判定を追加しました。（32bitOS環境が無いので、動作チェックは出来ませんが）